# How to draw a tree diagram with 90º degrees branches

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to replicate the following tree in LaTeX:
[image]

I'm having problems, because (1) I never drew a tree diagram with 90º degrees branches, like this, and (2) I never drew a tree diagram together with numbered examples.
I tried  using `tikz-qtree` and `forest`, but I didn't get anywhere. 
So I tried using `tabbing` environment to solve the numbered exemples problem, but now I don't know what package to use to draw the lines. 
This is my current (and horribly written) code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{0em} $(20)$ \= \hspace{2em} $n$ \= \hspace{1em} $s/(n)[n]$ \= 
\hspace{1em} $n/[s]$ \= \hspace{1em} $n$ \= \hspace{1em} $s/(n)$ \= 
\hspace{1em} $s/(n)//(s/(n))$ \= \hspace{1em} $s/(n)//(s/(n))[n]$ \= 
\hspace{1em} $n$ \= \hspace{1em} $n/(n)$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(21)$\= \hspace{37.5em} $n$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(22)$\= \hspace{17.5em} $s/(n)$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(23)$\= \hspace{30em} $s/(n)$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(24)$\= \hspace{20,5em} $s$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(25)$\= \hspace{14em} $n$\\~\\
\hspace{0em} $(26)$\= \hspace{6em} $s$\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]
Can anyone give me some help on how to resolve this nightmare I'm having to replicate the tree diagram of the first image?

Comment: I wonder if you could use `prooftrees` for this ....

Answer (score 11):

Here's a version using `forest`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
declare count register=labelcount,
enumerate/.style={labelcount=#1,
for tree={content/.pgfmath=labelcount, labelcount-=1},
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}for tree={grow=north,forked edge,math content}
[
[s,no edge
    [n
        [s
            [s/(n)
                [n,tier=21
                    [n/(n), tier=top]
                    [n,tier=top]] 
                [{s/(n)//(s/(n))[n]},tier=top ]
                [s/(n)
                    [s/(n)//(s/(n))),tier=top ]
                    [s/(n),tier=top ]
                ]
            ]
            [n,tier=top]
         ]
        [{n/[s]},tier=top ]
    ]
    [{s/(n)[n]},tier=top ]
    [n,tier=top ]
]
[,for tree=no edge,delay={enumerate={26},for tree={content={(#1)}}}
    [[[[[,tier=21 [,tier=top ]]]]]]]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Explanation of the code

- We use the `edges` library from `forest` to make easy square branches.
- We use `grow=north` to make the tree upside down.
- The use of the `tier` key allows all the terminal nodes of the tree to be aligned at the top of the tree.  It is also used to separate line (21) from (22) since in the tree they are at the same level of embedding, but in numbering they are not. By aligning the nodes in the tree with the nodes in the numbering we achieve the desired result.
- The numbering is done with what is essentially a phantom root node that dominates both the tree and the numbers.
- The numbers are calculated semi-automatically by giving the number for the root node using the `enumerate=...` key and counting down from there. Again, the `tier` key is used keep the alignment correct.

Comment: Interesting (+1, of course). It might be better not to rely on `tempcounta`, though. Why not use a new count for this, which is less likely to run into conflicts? I realise that's not very likely, but still ....

Comment: @cfr I was hoping you'd drop by with some comments. I just assumed that `tempcounta` was always local, and unlikely to interfere with other uses of it.  What I'd really like to do is to number the nodes 'bottom up' (in the tree sense) from 20 instead of having to precalculate the last number and count down.  Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I was actually thinking that's how I'd do it. And I'd add the root and numbers automatically, if possible. `tempcounta` is local to the `forest` group, but not otherwise local. So it is unlikely to conflict, but might if, say, the OP tries to combine this code with code from another answer. (If they write additional code themselves, presumably, they know enough to avoid that, but I'm thinking more of an attempt to combine your answer with some other one.)

Comment: @cfr There was a comma missing in the label branch. I've updated and made a counter.

Comment: I hope you don't mind: I've added an answer now my brain has started working again.

Comment: If you do, just say and I'll delete. But it is a bit much for a comment.

Comment: By the way, I don't think the use of `tier` is separating those nodes: it is only because you also have nodes with numbers on those tiers and those nodes bear the parent-child relationship to each other that you get the required distance. At least, I think that's right ....

Comment: I should have said above 'I was actually thinking that's NOT how I'd do it'. My brain really wasn't functioning yesterday, it seems.

Comment: @cfr No problem at all. It's a very fancy solution. :)

Comment: I got rather carried away. Also, I didn't mean that your approach was bad - it seemed very good to me - but literally just that it wasn't just how I would have gone about it.

Comment: @cfr The `tier=21` is required otherwise the `n` and the `(s/n)` will be on the same level. The `tier=22` is superfluous.  As for getting carried away, https://xkcd.com/1205/. :)

Comment: What I meant was that, if you didn't have other nodes with those tiers, you wouldn't get the spacing. Or if those other nodes didn't have to have the required spacing themselves. That is, it is the label nodes which make it work and not just the `tier=21` etc.

Comment: @cfr Oh, yes you're right. The alignment is being done with the numbers.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow' = up]
  \tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style = {draw,
      edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.north)
        -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
    frontier/.style = {distance from root = 180pt},
  }

  % tree
  \Tree [.s [n ]
            [s/(n)[n] ]
            [.n [n/[s] ]
                [.s [n ]
                    [.s/(n) [.s/(n) [s/(n) ] 
                                    [s/(n)//(s/(n)) ] ]
                            [s/(n)//(s/(n))[n] ]
                            [ [.n [.n ]
                                [.n/(n) ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

  % labels
  \foreach \y/\lbl in {0/26,30/25,60/24,90/23,120/22,150/21,180/20} {
    \node[xshift = -3cm, yshift = \y pt] at (0, 0){\small(\lbl)}; 
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an adaption of [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433753/) which is designed to be a bit more user-friendly. To produce the tree, simply add

```
enumerated,
enum'=<start line number>
```

where `<start line number>` is the number for the first line. The `enumerated` style will try to figure out how many lines are required, format the tree and number the lines. It is not necessary to add the phantom root or nodes for the numbers explicitly: these nodes will all be added automatically.

The only case where you need to help out are cases where extra lines are needed because two nodes which are at the same structural level should be placed on different lines.

The upshot of this is that

```
\begin{forest}
  enumerated,
  enum'=20,
  [S
      [n
          [s
              [s/(n)
                  [n,tier=21
                      [n/(n)]
                      [n]] 
                  [{s/(n)//(s/(n))[n]} ]
                  [s/(n),tier=22
                      [s/(n)//(s/(n))) ]
                      [s/(n) ]
                  ]
              ]
              [n]
          ]
          [{n/[s]} ]
      ]
      [{s/(n)[n]} ]
      [n ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: <code>enumerated</code> Forest style]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{% addaswyd o gôd Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433753/
  declare count register=enum,
  enum'=100,
  declare toks register=enum tiers,
  enum tiers=,
  declare boolean register=enum toggle,
  not enum toggle,
  enumerated/.style={
    enum tiers=enum@tier@\foresteregister{enum},
    for tree={
      math content,
      grow=90,
    },
    forked edges,
    delay={
      tempcountc/.max={level}{tree},
      tempcountc'+=1,
      tempcountb/.register=enum,
      while={
        >R_> {tempcountc}{0}
      }{
        tempcountc'-=1,
        not enum toggle,
        where={
          > O R = {level} {tempcountc}
        }{
          if n children=0{
            tier/.process={Rw{enum}{enum@tier@##1}}
          }{
            if tier={}{
              tier/.process={Rw{tempcountb}{enum@tier@##1}},
              if={>R! RR=! & {enum toggle} {tempcountb}{enum} }{ +enum tiers/.process={Rw{tempcountb}{enum@tier@##1,}}, enum toggle } {}
            }{
              +enum tiers/.process={Ow{tier}{##1,}}
            }
          },
        }{},        
        tempcountb'+=1,
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      replace by={[, phantom, for tree={grow=90}, append, temptoksa/.option=name, split register={enum tiers}{,}{enum label}
        ]%
      },
    },
    before packing={
      delay={
        tempcounta/.register=enum,
        for nodewalk={reverse={fake=r,while nodewalk valid={l}{l}}}{content/.process={Rw{tempcounta}{(##1)}}, typeset node, tempcounta'+=1},
      }
    }
  },
  enum label/.style={
    prepend={[, grow=90, tier=#1, no edge, name=#1]},
    enum parent/.process={Rw{temptoksa}{{##1}{#1}}},
    temptoksa=#1,
  },
  enum parent/.style 2 args={
    before packing={
      for nodewalk={name=#1}{append=#2}
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  enumerated,
  enum'=20,
  [S
      [n
          [s
              [s/(n)
                  [n,tier=21
                      [n/(n)]
                      [n]] 
                  [{s/(n)//(s/(n))[n]} ]
                  [s/(n),tier=22
                      [s/(n)//(s/(n))) ]
                      [s/(n) ]
                  ]
              ]
              [n]
          ]
          [{n/[s]} ]
      ]
      [{s/(n)[n]} ]
      [n ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```